How to make texts which are different in the number of characters start from the same place?
My design looks like the picture below not aligned well vertically



.results {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  height: 360px;
  justify-content: space-evenly;
}

.results .box {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-around;
  text-align: justify;
}
<div class="sum">
  <div class="title">Summary</div>
  <div class="results">
    <div class="box">
      <div>Reaction</div>
      <div class="score">80 / 100</div>
    </div>
    <div class="box">
      <div>Memory</div>
      <div class="score">92 / 100</div>
    </div>
    <div class="box">
      <div>Verbal</div>
      <div class="score">61 / 100</div>
    </div>
    <div class="box">
      <div>Visual</div>
      <div class="score">72 / 100</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>



Sadly, "text-align: justify;" makes no difference when the flex is in action
I know that the "justify-content: space-evenly;" is the reason they are not aligned well, but I wanted to know if there is a solution that allows me to still use the flex and still make them align well.

For the box divs, use space-between


.results {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  height: 360px;
  /*    justify-content: space-evenly; */
}

.results .box {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  text-align: justify;
  outline: 1px solid red;
}
<div class="sum">
  <div class="title">Summary</div>
  <div class="results">
    <div class="box">
      <div>Reaction</div>
      <div class="score">80 / 100</div>
    </div>
    <div class="box">
      <div>Memory</div>
      <div class="score">92 / 100</div>
    </div>
    <div class="box">
      <div>Verbal</div>
      <div class="score">61 / 100</div>
    </div>
    <div class="box">
      <div>Visual</div>
      <div class="score">72 / 100</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>



